# Database Schema question

Tags: database, database-design, schema

I am having a difficult time deciding how to handle a business requirement in my database schema.  I have a lot of tables in the database, but there are only three I need to deal with for this problem: Courses, PersonnelCourses, and Personnel.

- Courses is a list of Courses
- Personel
  is a list of Personnel
- PersonnelCourses is a list of Courses
  that Personnel have **taken**.

In courses there is a column called Universal.  If a course is universal, that means all Personnel must take that course.

I need to generate a list of all the universal courses that Personnel **must take**, but the only way I am able to generate this list is with a cross join / cartesian join:

> select P.LastName, C.Name 
>   from Courses C, Personnel P
>   where Universal = 1

From that I want to do a left join onto PersonnelCourses so that I can have a list of all the Personnel and the Courses they **must** take as well as the courses they have taken.  I'm thinking this would all be easier if there was a many to many table between Personnel and Courses.  But if all Personnel are going to be in this middle table anyway, isn't that a bit redundant?

Is there a better way to handle this?

### Much appreciated,

-Matt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a list of courses that everybody has to take. Why not just take this list and work with it, instead of repeating the same list for every personnel row? I don't understand why you are trying to multiply your result set.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't your PersonnelCourses establishing a many to many relationship between a Persons and Courses? If it isn't then I am not sure, If it is then...

```
select *

from Personnel_Courses 
    inner join Person on... /*get the Person details*/
    inner join Courses on... /*get the Course details*/

where Course.Universal = 1 and Person.Id = @Id
```

would tell you what universal courses they have taken...

and then

```
select *

from Courses

where Courses.Universal = 1 and Course.Id not in (
        select Course.Id from Personnel_Courses 
        inner join Person on... /*get the Person details*/
        inner join Courses on... /*get the Course details*/
        where Course.Universal = 1 and Person.Id = @Id
        )
```

Would give you the universal courses that they haven't taken...

To me it might be easier to do the 2nd in your code (Get the first query results, Do a select from the Course table to get all the universal and then do a comparison...)

Answer (score 1):

This is a topic [Database Normalization](http://databases.about.com/od/specificproducts/a/normalization.htm) that books have been written on
 and part of why you want to do this is [DRY](http://www.artima.com/intv/dry.html) or don't repeat yourself.

So to answer your question about a better way - I would answer no.

Answer (score 0):

All personnel will not be in the personnelcourses table, only personnel who have taken courses.

I think you design is fine. You just need to tweak your query to get what your after.

In a subquery pull the courses the personnel have taken. Then in an outer query select all the courses that the personnel must take and do a left outer join with the subquery.

```
Select a.CourseName, b.PersonName from Courses a, 
(select P.LastName, C.Name from Courses C, Personnel P, PersonnelCourses pc 
  c.courseid = pc.courseid and
  p.personnelid = pc.personnelid and
  c.Universal = 1)  b 
where
a.courseid += b.courseid order by courseid
```

It would probably be best to filter by personnel, if this is for a report. That way you would see all of the courses required including the ones taken per person.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this (using the existing structure)?

```
SELECT P.LastName, C.Name, 1 as Taken  
FROM Courses C   
  INNER JOIN PersonnelCourses PC ON (C.CourseID=PC.CourseID)  
  INNER JOIN Personnel P ON (P.PersonID=PC.PersonID)  
WHERE(C.Universal = 1)  

UNION  

SELECTP.LastName, C.name, 0 as Taken  
FROM Courses C, Personnel P   
WHERE (Universal = 1) and   
   NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Courses C2 
             INNER JOIN PersonnelCourses PC2 ON (C.CourseID=PC.CourseID)
             INNER JOIN Personnel P2 ON (P.PersonID=PC.PersonID)
             WHERE (Universal = 1)  and 
                    (PC2.CourseID=C.CourseID) and       
                    (P2.PersonID=PC2.PersonID)
             )
```

Answer (score 0):

`Universal` is a two-value (boolean) attribute of `Course`, right? In that case, consider normalizing further. Redesign so that `UniversalCourse` is a table, not a column on `Course`. That table would have a single column referencing the course. To find all universal courses, simply select everything from this table. Now you can shorten your cartesian join considerably since you have to multiply `Personnel` only by the UniversalCourse table, having eliminated the `where Universal = 1` clause.